# How can I specify SQLServer and Database during Installation in SetUpProject?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, setup-project

I have an application that using database. Also I'm going to make a setup project for it. Application will use existing database, so I need to specify Server Name, Database name, login and password during installation. Is it possible? And what should I do?

P.S. I'm using Visual Studio 2010, and creating Setup Project for my solution.

P.S.S. I want have dialog like this one.

[image]

Comment: Is this `.udl` dialog you want to access in your setup project?

Comment: @HassanNisar, If I can. But first of all I want to have any dialog to specify Server name and other setting.

Comment: I think this is not possible. Setup project gives you option to specify pre-requisite like dll or .net framework but not db of SQL Server.